# Can't inject EntityManager instance after upgrade to spring-boot-2.2.6

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

After upgrade to spring-boot-2.2.6 from 2.2.5, inject EntityManager instance by `@PersistenceContext` failed. What rules be changed?

```
@Repository
class MyDaoImpl @Autowired constructor(
  @PersistenceContext private val em: EntityManager,
  private val repository: MyJpaRepository
) {
  ...
}
```

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
  No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' available: 
  expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Error gone if I force config spring-boot-autoconfigure to 2.2.5 with spring-boot-2.2.6.

Comment: What was your previous `spring-data-jpa` version?

Comment: spring-data-jpa-2.2.5

Comment: Finally I found this problem cause by spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6. When I force config spring-boot-autoconfigure to 2.2.5 with spring-boot-2.2.6, error gone. So I change my question to spring-boot-2.2.6

Comment: Raise a [spring-boot/issue/20996](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20996).

Comment: I confirmed this fixed by spring-boot-2.2.7